# Change from CharSequence to String for Set<CharSequence> & Map<CharSequence, Object>

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, dictionary, set

**Scenario 1:**

I got a `Set<CharSequence>` from **somewhere**, which means **I have no control on how this set has been created**.

```
Set<CharSequence> dataSet = GET_DATA_SET();
```

I would like to convert the data from `Set<CharSequence>` to `Set<String>`. Is there an efficient way to do this conversion without iterate over each element?

**Scenario 2:**

I also get another data as a `HashMap` type (Again, I have no control on the creation part for this Map data) :

```
Map<CharSequence, Car> dataMap = GET_DATA_MAP();
```

Is there an efficient way to convert this Map to `Map<String, Car>` without iteration ?

Comment: But `Set<CharSequence>` could contain non-string objects. So, it is not safe to do so.

Comment: I got these data from somewhere, and I am sure there is no non-string objects. This is out of the scope of my question.

Comment: Answers should consider "without iterate" fact of the question. Not sure it is possible as even if any api provides that it would also be iterating.

Comment: Thanks all. I decide to iterate over each element & convert to String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like *Eng.Fouad* is mentioned not all `CharSequence` is `String`.

So we must invoke `toString()` method.

Just use:

```
 Set<CharSequence> dataSet = new HashSet<CharSequence>(Arrays.asList("a","b"));
    Set<String> output = new HashSet<String>();

    for(CharSequence c : dataSet){
        output.add(c.toString());
    }
```

*Pretty simple and clear*

Comment: I decide to iterate over each element and convert to String for safety's sake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the object are `String`s, then you can do a (unchecked) cast, with the risk that if you assumption becomes wrong, you will get a `ClassCastException`:

```
Map<CharSequence, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Map untypedDataMap = dataMap;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, Object> stringDataMap = untypedDataMap;
```

Note that this is quite risky, specially if the `Map` comes from an external library. I would loop over the `Map` to convert each `CharSequence` to a `String`.

Your problem is based on the asumption that the loop would be inefficient, but are you sure of this? And how would it be a problem in your case? Modern compiler and hardware are very efficient, it is possible that you don't even notice a difference with a loop.

Comment: Or just use `Map<String, Object> stringDataMap = (Map) dataMap;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there is no non-string objects, simply cast your object to `Set<String>` using

```
(Set<String>)((Object)dataSet);
```

Example:

```
(Set<String>)((Object)new HashSet<CharSequence>()));
```

But this is very dirty and unsafe trick.

Edit:
As mentioned by @LaurentG, you can do

```
(Set<String>)((Set)dataSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 Set<String> dataSet = (Set<String>)(Set)GET_DATA_SET();
```

Comment: Remove `(Set<String>)`.

Comment: Thanks. I decide to iterate over each element & convert to String.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this wildcards:

```
Set<? extends CharSequence> dataSet;
Map<? extends CharSequence, Car> dataMap;
```

It's safe and proper. But you must remember that your method may return objects, which you will not be able to cast to some heirs of CharSequence

Comment: A `CharSequence` is not an appropriate set member: "This interface does not refine the general contracts of the equals and hashCode methods. The result of comparing two objects that implement CharSequence is therefore, in general, undefined. Each object may be implemented by a different class, and there is no guarantee that each class will be capable of testing its instances for equality with those of the other. It is therefore inappropriate to use arbitrary CharSequence instances as elements in a set or as keys in a map." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible to do without iteration in java core. Perhaps, you can use Guava to do that. Take a look at `Lists.transform` and `Collections2.transform`